# $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. For some positive integer $h$, $\mathbb{P}(X>h)>0$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let us consider a random variable $X$ which is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $1$, that is:
$$X\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0, 1\right)\tag{1}$$
Could I be sure that for *some* positive integer $h$ it holds true that:
$$\mathbb{P}\left(X>h\right)>0$$?
 That is, equivalently, could I be sure of the fact that it is not possible that $\mathbb{P}\left(X>h\right)=0$? If so, why? Has one to think of standard normal complementary cumulative distribution function?

---

I was thinking that knowing $(1)$ cannot make me sure of the fact that almost surely the random variable $X$ does not take values greater than $h$, since $h$ is just *some* positive integer, and it could be arbitrarily big. I am struggling with that, could you please help me understand?

Comment: $\int_c^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}/2}dx >0$ for any real number $c$.

Comment: $$\operatorname{Pr}(X>h)=\int_h^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$
Since $\exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2}\right)$ is positive nonzero $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, $\nexists h\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathrm{Pr}(X>h)=0.$

Comment: Thank you a lot @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Thank you a lot @K.defaoite